# Basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow V$ be a one-to-one and onto linear function. How to show that $V$ is a finite dimensional space with $dim(V)=dim(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Comment: @MS Relevant information should be added to post (it is better visible there than in the comments). Which is why I have edited your post to add the information yuo provided in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the canonical basis in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $v_i=f(e_i)\in V$.

Since $f$ is surjective, $V$ is generated by $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and so has finite dimension; moreover, $\dim V \le n$.

Since $f$ is injective, $v_1,\dots,v_n$  is linearly independent, and so $\dim V \ge n$.